# Default close operation in C++ (Windows form)

Tags: c++, hide, default

How can I change default close operation in c++ ?

If I push red X (in windows form app), I don't want close frame, but just hide it.

Comment: How do you know it just hides? Also, I would retag the question: E.g. The [tag:winforms] Tag will be much more useful than the rather meaningless [tag:default], [tag:operation], ... tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a windows form application most likely you already have some kind of message loop procedure (or if not you will have to implement one) and then in that handle  [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.a) message and minimize the window and return that the event has been handled so that the default implementation does not close the window. What technology are you using - MFC, ATL, Winforms?

**EDIT**

Since you've clarified that you are using windows forms this should work (small example showing how to add the closing event handler in the constructor and how to actually cancel the closing and minimize the window):

```
Form1(void)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //
    //TODO: Add the constructor code here
    //
    this->Closing += gcnew CancelEventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Closing);
}

void Form1_Closing( Object^ /*sender*/, System::ComponentModel::CancelEventArgs^ e )
{
    this->WindowState = FormWindowState::Minimized;
    e->Cancel = true;
}
```

More on the `Form::Closing` event can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx).

Comment: in java, I just add this lien:frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: See my edits, i think this should be pretty much what you need.